# Magic Trackpad / Mouse very spongy on Windows 7 with Bootcamp Update Drivers

Tags: windows, magic-trackpad, mouse

It seems to me that both, Magic Mouse and Magic Trackpad respond differently on Windows.
While using them with Mac OS X feels natural, on Windows 7 with drivers extracted from Bootcamp Upgrade, it feels spongy / laggy / delayed / with latency, no matter what the mouse settings are. So I feel like I'm not in touch with the mouse pointer (cursor).

It makes me sad that I should not be able to use this excellent hardware on my Windows PC, and I would like to know if this can be fixed.

Comment: How much memory do you have?

Comment: Can we do anything else to help you find an answer? Please edit or flag this if you need assistance.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced this as well (from MS mice in O SX and Apple mice in Win7).  I have reported this issue -- I think Apple's "doesn't work well with Windows" bugs get tossed on the back burner and forgotten (until they start to cause a stink).

In the mean time, this is what I have observed:

- Completely disconnecting hardware before restart helps (Unpair/disconnect/turn off everything)
- Microsoft USB hardware needs to be physically disconnected during/before reboot to work well in OS X
- Plan B -- Use VMware Fusion to run Windows.  How much is it really necessary to have fu only for serious hardware needs.  I do this just so that I can use my magic mouse and bluetooth keyboard without trouble.
- Have a cheap MS USB wireless arc mouse handy (the top-heavy laser resembles behavior of the magic mouse)

Other thoughts:

- I had this problem in Ubuntu also -- if my MS mouse was left connected during a reboot from Win to Ubuntu (and Ubuntu to Win), the mouse would act funny.  The problem was solved by disconnecting and reconnecting.

Answer (score 1):

In regards to the Magic Trackpad, I have seen this issue as well, and found it on other sites noted as a probably bug. The workaround they suggested, which I also found beforehand, was to do a physical click (press down to make it click). After that, it becomes responsive.

Comment: I was/am having this issue as well. Although, my trackpad wasn't lagging or delayed, it would start off fine, and then, over a period of time, it would start to loose sensitivity. It was like my trackpad couldn't read my finger on it. After reading user3719's answer, and making a physical click with the trackpad, it started working perfectly again, like I had just rebooted it. Killer trick, user3719. I don't know where you found that out, but it worked like a charm for me.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a problem with a bluetooth mouse under Windows 8 with Boot Camp. The mouse worked fine in OS X.

In the end I found there is a property on the wireless network card called 
'bluetooth collaboration' that can be enabled when in Windows. This fixed the problem for me and now the bluetooth mouse works perfectly.

Open Device Manager, find the network adapter and look at it's properties. On the advanced tab find Bluetooth Collaboration and make sure it is enabled.

http://blog.craigharvey.me/2012/09/08/macbook-pro-boot-camp-and-bluetooth-mice-in-windows/